# jQuery - hide div, then show on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a div that I want to slide down from behind another div when an arrow is clicked - then to hide again once a form button is clicked. I can code most of this, however I do not understand how to hide the div from view, then make it drop-down using slideToggle.

Edit: As suggested by people below (thanks), it turns out slideToggle() isn't what I need, but rather animate() - the code below doesn't seem to work, I've added a link to the jQuery UI but still nothing.

HTML

```
    <div class="schedule">
        <div class="scheduletop">
            <a href="/"><img src="/images/audit.png"></a>
        </div><!-- .scheduletop -->
        <div class="schedulebottom">
            <?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='61' title='Audit']"); ?>
        </div><!-- .schedulebutton -->
        <div class="thestuff">
            <h3>TEST!</h3>
        <div class="slide">
            CLICK TEST TO SLIDE
        </div><!-- .slide -->
        </div><!-- .thestuff -->
    </div><!-- .schedule -->
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".slide").click(function() {
        $(".thestuff").animate({"down": "150px"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `.slideToggle()` just animates the height of an element. You probably want to use `.animate()` to change the position of an element.

Comment: please don't remove your initial request when you edit

Answer (score 1):

`slideToggle()` isn't the function you should use in this situation. It only changes the height of the matched elements, while the `.animate()` method on the other hand can move your div in the desired direction, but it doesn't hide the element when the animation is finished, so you should use a callback if you want to achieve that. If you want to place a div behind another one, you should use the `z-index` css property.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not entirely sure what a callback function is; i'm new to jQuery.

The new code i have is below, but it doesn't animate as it should.

     $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".thestuff").click(function() {
            $(".slide").animate("{height": "150px"}, "slow");
        });
    });

Comment: If you want to move your div, then you should animate the margin with a negative number, like `animate({ marginTop: '-150px'}, slow);`, this will move your div up with 150px. A callback function is basically a function that is called when the animation finished. The jQuery animate() has a property, called `complete` which handles callbacks. You can read more on the topic at http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

As you were told you should use .animate().
I've made a simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cAyaV/3/).
here is the js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".thestuff").click(function () {
        $el = $(this).find(".slide");
        if (!$el.data('up')) {
            var h3Margin = parseInt($(this).children().eq(0).height(), 10);
            var margin = "-" + ($el.height() + h3Margin) + "px";
            $el.css("z-index", -10);
            $el.animate({
                "margin-top": margin
            });
            $el.data('up', true);
        } else {
            $el.animate({
                "margin-top": 0
            }, {
                complete: function () {
                    $el.css("z-index", 1);
                }
            });

            $el.data('up', false);
        }
    });
});
```

you can also use opacity instead of z-index but that's up to you

Comment: Thanks G3z. I posted a jsfiddle in an answer, could you tell me why it's better to use the code you posted as opposed to the code in the jsfiddle? I'm new to jQuery and would like to know/learn as much as possible.

Comment: as j08691 pointed out slideToggle() resizes the height of your element while I understod you wanted to move the element. My code is not "better", it just outputs a different different. if you are ok with resizing there's nothing wrong with your code

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(".slide").animate(
        { top: "+=150" }, 
        1000, 
        function () {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    );
```

The above code will animate your div down 150px by increasing the "top" attribute.  Then when it is finished with the animation it will hide your .slide div.

edit:
The "1000" in there says, take 1 second to complete the animation.

edit2: Oh, also make sure .slide has the attribute "position" set to "relative".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will give this a go! I'm curious though as to why the code i posted above works just as well - is there any reason why i should use the animate over the slideToggle() i posted in the jsfiddle?

Comment: slideToggle() make the element squish into nothing.  So if it starts at 400px tall, then it will gradually squish to 0px tall.  If this is the desired effect then go for it.  http://jsfiddle.net/Dtwigs/wJfDr/  See if that's what you want.  If not help me understand what you're going for and I'll help out.

Comment: Hi Dan, the idea was to simply slide open the div and then close it once a submit button in a form is pressed. Obviously slideToggle() would only be used for a single click in this case - can you tell me, with this in mind, if it's better for me to use your code or the one i posted in the jsfiddle? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, use slideToggle() for that.  You were on the right track.  Sorry, I got confused by all these other answers.  Thought you were looking for something else.  Cheers. (p.s. I think your jsFiddle has been removed from the question)

Comment: Hi Dan, the jsfiddle is in an answer i posted to my own question. I was hoping maybe you can help me a little more. I've added the code i've mentioned in the jsfiddle and added a new div, slidecontain, this is position absolutely. However, now, when i click the "click to slide", it opens the slide div ABOVE the click to slide button. See http://odesk.n8geeks.com/ (the top part is ugly, i know, that will change haha).

Comment: Ok, fixed it. Simply stopped the element from being absolutely position and floated it right inside the element i needed - now it opens below instead of above the click div.

Comment: There you go!  Good job. It definitely gets confusing as to why things behave the way they are when you have to pay attention to HTML, CSS & JS.  Good luck with the project!

Answer (score -1):

Okay so it seems that i can achieve what i'm looking for with slideToggle() afterall, i just had to set the main content container to not show until clicked (added display: none; to CSS).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".slide").click(function() {
    $(".thestuff").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

For anyone who may be trying to find a similar solutions check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JttU/)